# Cannot write ( in ideavim in pycharm console (conflict with key binding)

Tags: vim, console, pycharm, ideavim

As the title says, I cannot use ( in ideavim in pycharm console.

I have been reconfig ideavim to work exactly the way I want it in pycharm. 
The only problem now it when I am in console mode I cannot type (.

in vim normal mode ( go to the first line a paragraph where a collection of emtpy lines itself are counted as paragraph.

How can I disable/change this?

Edit:

I just tried to diable it `map ( <Nop>` which diable shift + ( in vim normal mode, but I still can't type ( in console

Thank you

Comment: Normally ( is just referred to as (, not shift-( or `<S-(>`

Comment: I edited the post. I tried it and problem still stands.